# How to open a third party HTML project from a web application ,in a separate browser tab

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a Java web application. And I want to add a `help` component to that.(So that user clicks on a `help` button the help page will open in a separate tab)

The `help` page is a separate HTML project with it's own CSS and JS. (let's say it's a small separate HTML project)
. And I can manually run it by clicking the `index.html` file in that project.(`help/index.html`)

So how can I add a button in my Web Application so that a user clicks on it , it will open the `help` page in a new browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

You put your web application:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('help/index.html', '_blank');"> Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **target** attribute of the **a** element and set it to **_blank**.

```html
<a href="help/index.html" target="_blank">Help</a>
```